# Druid kafka Ingestion Process Data Drop

Tags: druid

My Druid Server is running in single-server and I'm Ingesting 30M records in One Datasource from Kafka. There is 16GB RAM and 100GB Swap Memory allocated.Java Memory Heap size is 15.62GB.

Druid also contains another datasource with 2.6M records and that supervisor is suspended.

Now there is 4.5M records stored successfully but When Records increases to 6M there is problem stats    " Unable to reconnect to Zookeeper service, Session expired event received " and then Data Dropped to 4.5M and reinstating, and again same process repeated with records goes to up at some point like 6.2M and then same error occurred and data dropped to 4.5M . then After 4-5 Hours Druid Service restarts and record in datasource starts from 4.5M.

Segment granularity is set to HOUR.

Following is the statistics of Memory usage in system

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G         15G        165M         36K        160M         83M
Swap:           99G         45G         54G
```

What Should I have to do? Is this a problem of Memory?